# How to check if a prompt field in my flowform bot exist in my database

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, botframework, formflow

I'm creating a bot using Bot Framework, in web channel and direct line.
i Have a luis dialog which call some  forms ( flow form ) .

I have to ask for each form the contract number and some other data . How to store just one time contract number and to go ahead to other field and that to response the right answer for that contract number of the user.

- i was trying to ask in the begging the contract number and name of the person and to check if they match..if yes  to let the user to use the bot...but i cannot find the right logic code.

Can you help me please with any idea how to ask just one time the contract number and to use in all my dialog and forms ?
Below is my code :

MessagesController.cs :

```
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{  
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
        Activity isTypingReply = activity.CreateReply();
        isTypingReply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
        await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(isTypingReply);

        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            activity.Locale = "en-US";
            Helpers.SaveActivityDataToDB(activity);
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new LuisDialog());
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

Luis.cs

```
[LuisIntent("Greeting")]
public async Task Greeting(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    await context.SayAsync(text: "Welcome");
}

[LuisIntent("balance")]
public async Task balance(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    var balanca = new FormDialog<BalanceForm>(
        new BalanceForm(),
        BalanceForm.BuildForm,
        FormOptions.PromptInStart,
        result.Entities);
    context.Call<BalanceForm>(balanca, BalanceCompleted);
}

private async Task BalanceCompleted(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<BalanceForm> result)
{
    BalanceForm form = null;
    try
    {
        form = await result;
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
    }

    if (form == null)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Try again please!");
    }
    else
    {
        //call the LossForm service to complete the form fill
        var message = $"Thnx";
        await context.PostAsync(message);
    }
    context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
}
```

BalanceForm.cs

```
[Serializable]
public class BalanceForm
{
    [Prompt("What is your contract number?")]
    public string contract;

    public static IForm<BalanceForm> BuildForm()
    {
        OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<BalanceForm> wrapUpRequest = async 
        (context, state) =>
        {
            using (BotModelDataContext BotDb = new BotModelDataContext())
            {
                //search in database 

                string wrapUpMessage = "Dear " + house.Firstname + "," + "your  balance is " + house.Balance;
                await context.PostAsync(wrapUpMessage);       
            };
            return new FormBuilder<BalanceForm>()
                .Message("We have to ask you some information")
                .Field(nameof(contract))
                .OnCompletion(wrapUpRequest)
                //.Confirm("Are you sure: Yes or No ")
                .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can you help me please with any idea how to ask just one time the contract number and to use in all my dialog and forms ?

Based on your requirement, I create a sample to prompt user for contract number and save the value in **UserData** so that I can get the contract number that user provided from **UserData** in child dialog(s). The following sample code is for your reference.

*In RootDialog:*

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        // calculate something for us to return
        int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

        var contractnumber = "";

        if (!context.UserData.TryGetValue<string>("contract_number", out contractnumber))
        {
            //prompt for contract number

            PromptDialog.Text(
            context: context,
            resume: AfterGetContractNumber,
            prompt: "Please provide your contract number.",
            retry: "Please try again."
        );
        }
        else
        {
            await context.Forward(new BaiscLuisDialog(), AfterLuisDialog, context.Activity, CancellationToken.None);

        }
    }

    private async Task AfterGetContractNumber(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        string contractnumber = await result;

        context.UserData.SetValue<string>("contract_number", contractnumber);

        await context.PostAsync($"OK, received your contract number: {contractnumber}.");

        context.Done(this);
    }


    private async Task AfterLuisDialog(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}
```

*In BaiscLuisDialog:*

```
[LuisIntent("balance")]
public async Task BalanceIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    //call BalanceForm
    //and pass contract number that user provided to BalanceForm contract_number
    var balanca = new Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.FormDialog<BalanceForm>(new BalanceForm() { contract_number = context.UserData.GetValue<string>("contract_number") }, 
        BalanceForm.BuildForm, 
        Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.FormOptions.PromptInStart, 
        result.Entities);

    context.Call<BalanceForm>(balanca, BalanceCompleted);
}

private async Task BalanceCompleted(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<BalanceForm> result)
{
    context.Wait(MessageReceived);
}
```

*In BalanceForm:*

```
[Serializable]
public class BalanceForm
{
    public string contract_number;

    [Prompt("What is your contract number?")]
    public string contract;

    public string your_other_field;
    public static IForm<BalanceForm> BuildForm()
    {
        OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<BalanceForm> wrapUpRequest = async
        (context, state) =>
        {
            //using (BotModelDataContext BotDb = new BotModelDataContext())
            //{
            //    //search in database 

            //    string wrapUpMessage = "Dear " + house.Firstname + "," + "your  balance is " + house.Balance;
            //    await context.PostAsync(wrapUpMessage);
            //};

            //your code logic here

            var contractnumber = "";

            context.UserData.TryGetValue<string>("contract_number", out contractnumber);

            string wrapUpMessage = " Form completed! Your contract number is " + contractnumber;
            var replymes = context.MakeMessage();
            replymes.Text = wrapUpMessage;

            await context.PostAsync(replymes);
        };

        return new FormBuilder<BalanceForm>()
            .Message("We have to ask you some information")
            .Field(new FieldReflector<BalanceForm>(nameof(contract)).SetActive(state => state.contract_number == null))
            .Field(nameof(your_other_field))
            .OnCompletion(wrapUpRequest)
            //.Confirm("Are you sure: Yes or No ")
            .Build();
    }
}
```

*Test result:*

[image]